# Filter page type in multi site

Tags: episerver

I have a multi site setup.I have to perform some functionality on a particular pagetype (article page).
For this i have the below code that will allow me to loop in through all the sites. The part where I am stuck is to get the list of article pages that is available in the site i.e. getting all the article pages based on the site it is traversing.

````
            Queue<ContentReference> todo = new Queue<ContentReference>();
            siteDefinitionRepository.List().ToList().ForEach(sd =>
            {
                todo.Enqueue(sd.StartPage);
            });
            while (todo.Count > 0)
            {
                var siteContentReference = todo.Dequeue();
                var masterContentRepository = contentRepository.Get<IContent>(siteContentReference);

                var site = siteDefinitionResolver.GetByContent(masterContentRepository.ContentLink, true);
                var startPage = contentLoader.Get<StartPage>(site.StartPage);

                //fetch all the article pages belonging to the site within the loop
            
            }```


Any input is helpful
````

Comment: Which CMS version? Do you have "Search & Navigation" (previously "Episerver Find")?

Comment: I am using CMS 11.Thanks will check with search & navigation.

Comment: Is there any other approach other than search & navigation to achieve this. For some reason, i cant use search and navigation.I need to get all the article pages that has a xyz property set to a particular value.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using `FindPagesWithCriteria`.

Be beware: it is *uncached*, so you need to take steps to ensure performance.

Here is an example, based on [Jon Jones' blog](https://www.jondjones.com/learn-episerver-cms/episerver-developers-tutorials/episerver-api-explained/findpageswithcriteria-how-to-search-for-pages-within-episerver/), which retrieves all pages where the `PageName` property has a specific value:

```
var criterias = new PropertyCriteriaCollection
{
    new PropertyCriteria()
    {
        Name = "PageName",
        Type = PropertyDataType.String,
        Condition = EPiServer.Filters.CompareCondition.Equal,
        Value = "Some value"
    }
};

var repository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IPageCriteriaQueryService>();

var pages = repository.FindPagesWithCriteria(
    PageReference.StartPage,
    criterias);
```